# Array values as strings

Tags: python, arrays, string

I currently have a for loop that is going to replace strings in a text file, but I want them to replace these strings using variables that I have already defined.

```
k_constant_vec = [.15707963267,.2221441469,.31415926535,.35124073655,.44428829381,.88857658763,1.33286488145];

for t in range(1, len(k_constant_vec)):

     infile = open('/home/john/projects/simplecodes/textreplace/ex22.i')

     outfile = open('/home/john/projects/simplecodes/textreplace/newex22-[t].i', 'w')

     replacements = {'k_constant = k_constant_vec[t-1]':'k_constant = k_constant_vec[t]','file_base = out':'file_base = out-[t]'}
        for line in infile:
            for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
                     line = line.replace(src, target)
            outfile.write(line)
            infile.close()
            outfile.close()
```

I basically want to use a for loop to create a bunch of new .i files. For example this will create 7 .i files that are labeled newex22-1, newex22-2, ect that each have different `k_constant = k_constant_vec[1]`, `k_constant = k_constant_vec[2]`, ect strings replaced in them.

Thanks

Comment: you will need to use `.format()` to accomplish your goals, as you cannot embed variables directly into strings like perl or php

Comment: `'path/newex22-'+repr(t)+'.i'`

Comment: Are you supposed to be putting the values from `k_constant_vec` into the files, or just the indices?

Comment: Thanks George. I'll check to see if this works in a minute for that part. And yes, jonrsharpe I need the values from the k_constant_vec as strings in the .i file as they are in the array.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few minor bugs/styling issues with your code. It's also unclear why you have infile. The following is a more pythonic way of what I think you are trying to do:

```
k_constant_vec = [.15707963267,.2221441469,.31415926535,.35124073655,.44428829381,.88857658763,1.33286488145];
file_prefix = '/home/john/projects/simplecodes/textreplace/newex22-[%s].i'
for index in range(len(k_constant_vec)):
  with open(file_prefix % (index + 1), 'wb') as f:
    f.write('k_constant = %s' % k_constant_vec[index])
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. I want to edit the file ex22.i and replace strings with a for loop creating new files. This just makes a bunch of empty files where k_constant = %s % k_constant_vec[index].

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it and I'll post what I did here in case anyone searches a similar problem. I used what george had suggested in combination with using %s and % in the for loop.

```
k_constant_vec = [.15707963267,.2221441469,.31415926535,.35124073655,.44428829381,.88857658763,1.33286488145];

for t in range(0,len(k_constant_vec)):
    infile = open('/home/john/projects/simplecodes/textreplace/ex22.i')
    outfile = open('/home/john/projects/simplecodes/textreplace/newex22-'+repr(t)+'.i', 'w')
    replacements = {'k_constant = .15707963267':'k_constant = %s' % k_constant_vec[t],'file_base = out':'file_base = out-'+repr(t)}
    #use default k_constant from ex22.i file
    for line in infile:
        for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        outfile.write(line)
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

The whole point of using infile is to preserve the format of the text file.